# Issues understanding homebrew on my mac running 10.7 os/x

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

I tried installing postgres on my mac using homebrew.

It's not working.

How do I remove what homebrew put in for me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about 'brew list' to see what you installed and 'brew remove [your-program]'? I guess this is all in the brew manpage. And even more info on this page about [PostgreSQL on OS X](http://russbrooks.com/2010/11/25/install-postgresql-9-on-os-x).